# Nested SQL - Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the difference between these two queries? Using the Northwind database, When I run the queries they give me different results. However I cannot understand what causes the difference.

```
select *
from (
    select top 100 percent orderid, customerid
    from orders
    order by OrderID
) as D
```

And this?

```
select top 100 percent orderid, customerid
from orders
order by OrderID
```

Comment: first one will return `unordered` list, 2nd one returns `ordered`

Comment: I suspect your results are actually not different, just in a different sort order.  If you sort your output in the same manner your results should match right up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one is guaranteed to return the rows ordered by `OrderId`.

The first one will return all the rows, but the ordering is not guaranteed because there is no `ORDER BY` in the outer query.